# Unexpected ESlint "no-mutating-props" error in this Vue3 code

Tags: vuejs3

ESLint gives me `Unexpected mutation of "objVehicle" prop.eslint(vue/no-mutating-props)` on the part `objVehicle.engine_options` at the v-model property. Is this a false positive? It seems I'm following the correct procedure here? Is the ESLint warning correct and if so, why?

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent
            v-model:engineOptions="objVehicle.engine_options"
            @update:engineOptions="emit('update:objVehicle', objVehicle)"
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
    import ChildComponent from "@....vue"

    const props = defineProps({
        objVehicle: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    })

    const emit = defineEmits(['update:objVehicle'])

</script>
```

I am aware that this code is somewhat irregular, as I pass a property of an object to the child component, but as far as I understand the docs, this should be allowed (and it seems to work fine). Also, changing to the (more traditional?) code below does not remove the warning:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent
            v-model:objVehicle="objVehicle"
            @update:objVehicle="(event) => emit('update:objVehicle', event)"
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
    import ChildComponent from "@....vue"

    const props = defineProps({
        objVehicle: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    })

    const emit = defineEmits(['update:objVehicle'])

</script>
```

The Child Component. Although ESLint isn't aware of this code (or is it?) So, maybe not very relevant.

```js
<template>Form elements for the engineOptions property are placed here...</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    const props = defineProps({
        engineOptions: {
            type: Object,
            required: false, // create on-demand
        },
    })

    const emit = defineEmits(['update:engineOptions'])

    const initEngineOptions = async () => {
        if (!Array.isArray(props.engineOptions)) {
            emit('update:engineOptions', [])
        }
    }

    const engineOptions= computed({
        get() {
            return props.engineOptions as TEngineOptions[]
        },
        set(newVal: TEngineOptions[] | undefined) {
            emit('update:engineOptions ', newVal)
        },
    })

    // Remove self
    const atRemove = () => {
        engineOptions.value = undefined
    }

</script>
```

What this does it it allows the engineOptions property on objVehicle to be created on-demand. The property is created on first use by the initEngineOptions() function.

Comment: I am pretty sure Vue3 doesnt like the fact that you pass a sub-object of a props, because it cannot know for sure that you wont modify the value of the it.  Can you share the child component ?

Comment: Thought so too, but I get the same warning when I only pass objVehicle. Added the (relevant parts of the) child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use v-model, that is explicitly saying that this props have a two way data binding. How ever as it is a prop so it should not.

replacing with v-bind does the trick, as it is how vue define a one way data binding

u can also use the syntax

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child-component
      :engineOptions="objVehicle.engine_options"
      @update:engineOptions="emit('update:objVehicle', objVehicle)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

which use v-bind under the hood

Comment: That does the trick indeed. Somehow find it a bit confusing, as the engineOptions property is (functionally) a two-way binding. I like the explicit v-model style, even though seeing the `@update:prop` you could mentally derive from that that its a two-way binding... Fixing it this way "feels" to me as fixing it by putting a sticker on the red light. Am I wrong in that?

Comment: This did gave me an idea. This also does not give me a warning: `:modelValue:engine_options="objVehicle.engine_options"`

Comment: Eslint is not that clever. 
So when you use v-model, it expect it to be mutated in the child component, even if it is not. his question is more like 'why would you ever want to mutate your props ? dont give this right to the child component'
about the fact that it is in fact a two-way binding, you are emitting to the parent, which will by it self update the child, so even if it looks it mutate it, it does not, it just inform the parent that it should. 
:modelvalue is not a v-model under the hood I believe, but a v-bind soi it make sense

Comment: if it did the trick, dont forget to set as answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer provided by Armand, I also found the following to work. It uses the Vue3 modelValue, and thus is a little more streamlined.

IMHO, this is also more verbose about it being a two-way binding, and also doesn't require you to manually specify the @update event. The only downside is that this does not support multiple v-models:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent
            v-model:="objVehicle.engine_options"
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { reactive } from 'vue'
    import ChildComponent from "@....vue"

    const props = defineProps({
        modelValue: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    })

    let objVehicle = reactive(props.modelValue)

</script>
```

Child Component:

```js
<template>Form elements for the engineOptions property are placed here...</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    const props = defineProps({
        modelValue: {
            type: Object,
            required: false, // create on-demand
        },
    })

    const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

    const initEngineOptions = async () => {
        if (!Array.isArray(props.modelValue)) {
            emit('update:modelValue', [])
        }
    }

    const engineOptions= computed({
        get() {
            return props.modelValue as TEngineOptions[]
        },
        set(newVal: TEngineOptions[] | undefined) {
            emit('update:engineOptions ', newVal)
        },
    })

    // Remove self
    const atRemove = () => {
        engineOptions.value = undefined
    }

</script>
```

The v-model seems to require the variable to be reactive, hence the wrapping in `reactive()` in the parent.